# How to use `scipy.optimize.linprog` for a more complicated objective function?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scientific-computing

Is there a way to solve a more complicated objective function using [`scipy.optimize.linprog`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html)? The problem takes the form

```
c^T * x / ((d^T * x)^T*e)
```

where `x = N x 1`, `c = N x 1`, `d = N x M` and `e = M x 1`.

Using an explicit function in [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) takes too long.

Comment: You could [transform your problem into a LP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming#Transformation_to_a_linear_program).

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this is actually a well know problem in optimization called linear fractional programming. There is a way to transform the variables and solve it with some additional constraints. I am not sure whether scipy linprog will work, but at least there is a path I can see.